# ActiveSupport notifications don't have a duration (the start- and end-time are exactly the same)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, notifications, activesupport

We use `ActiveSupport` notifications to log specific network calls (made with Faraday). In only one of the types of calls, when the code reaches...

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe(notification[:name]) do |_name, starts, ends, _, env|
  handle_notification(starts, ends, env, notification[:service], env[:request_headers][notification[:header]])
end
```

...the `starts` and `ends` are the same, so I can't calculate the duration of the call.

This happens on only one specific call, and the code is basically the same. However, I do notice that the calls that work properly were extracted to gems, but the calls that aren't working are not in gems. Not sure if it matters.

How can I debug/solve this?

Comment: Can you check that block is passed where you are generating these notifications? and it holds all the required code

Comment: it does get passed, so when I do `ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(..).duration` it equals 0.033 or something like that, which doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem while trying to pin down slow factories using `factory_girl` (now called [`factory_bot`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md), because we're all politically correct).

In my case it turns out use of [`travel_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html) was to blame. The way `travel_to` seems to work (unfortunately), is by essentially "freezing" time... That is, once `travel_to x` has been called, `Time.now` will return the value of `x` no matter how much time has passed between calls.

A workaround might involve using `travel_back`, or avoiding `travel_to` calls.

Answer (score -1):

The `start` and `end` values are `Time` objects.  If you just log the output of those values they appear just like a time/date value `2017-01-12 10:51:00 +0100`.

You have to convert those to milliseconds or microseconds to see the fine values.

You can convert a Time object to milliseconds with the following:

```
start.to_f * 1000
end.to_f * 1000
```

Then you can work with values like `1484216765256` which is in milliseconds and calculate duration by subtracting `end` from `start`.

Comment: This suggestion did not help in my case... If the OP had the same [issue I had](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55754455/119363), then the two `Time` instances (`starts` and `ends`) were literally the same, without even microseconds of difference.